# Laravel form placeholder not display correctly

Tags: laravel, char, placeholder, htmlspecialchars

I'm new with laravel and I do not know what's wrong with my forms. All placeholders display special non-translated HTML characters on my application online. But locally they are displayed very well. I checked and added this  but nothing changes. Someone can help me please

Comment: show your code example

Comment: If you're using HTML Laravel Collective correct way is: `Form::text('my-input', 'default value', ['placeholder' => 'My placeholder'])`

Comment: there's many reasons. paste the form code to check it